# Your favorite website/forum for Mac OS X Server?

Tags: mac, mac-osx, apple, osx-leopard

I'll get the ball rolling:

- http://discussions.apple.com/category.jspa?categoryID=96 Apple Discussions
- http://afp548.com
- http://macenterprise.org
- http://krypted.com/ Charles Edge's blog
- http://www.bombich.com/mactips Mike Bombich (re: deployment)
- http://www.macwindows.com (re: Windows integration)

Answer (score 5):

These won't be entirely new to you, since you follow afp548.com and macenterprise.org, but Nigel Kersten, currently at Google, publishes very useful tips here:

http://explanatorygap.net

Greg Neagle, currently of Disney, has maintained an excellent blog here:

http://managingosx.wordpress.com

And an old favourite, [Mac OS X Hints](http://macosxhints.com), busy and eclectic as it is, is quite often useful for Mac OS X Server. The sites you've already mentioned provide an excellent start - we're lucky that, with Mac OS X Server, we have a community of experts willing to fill in the gaps in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

- http://xsanity.com

  All things Xsan

Answer (score 1):

- http://arstechnica.com/apple/

Answer (score 1):

1. [Make Mac Work](http://www.makemacwork.com/) by Ellis Jordan Bojar is a great site
2. [The Bits](http://www.dreness.com/blog/) (just found this one, but it looks good)